# pass objects from C# to C++ getting "cannot use this indirection"?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have this function in C++:

```
struct MyObject
{
}

testAlgorithm(array<String^>^ algorithms, MyObject^ myObject)
```

I got this problem complaining about `MyObject`:

> error C3699: '^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'MyObject'

But that is not the case with `array<String^>^`

Why is that and how to fix it?

In another situation, if i do it:

```
testAlgorithm(array<String^>^ algorithms, MyObject myObject)
```

Then in C#, I have to call:

```
testAlgorithm(string[] algorithms, MyObject *myObject);
```

I construct the `MyObject` in C# and declare it but how to pass it to testAlgorithm as: `*myObject` in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be that you are actually using C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `^` on `MyObject` because it is not a managed class. To declare it as managed struct (that will, by the way be copied if it is passed as parameter), you would need to use `value struct` instead of `struct`.

If you want your object to be passed as a reference (without copying, which is probably what you want), you should declare it as `ref class`.

Comment: you are right. It solved my problem thanks. I have another problem related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839972/how-to-convert-from-lpwstr-to-const-char do you have any idea?