# how to convert from LPWSTR to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, c++-cli

After getting a struct from C# to C++ using C++/CLI:

```
public value struct SampleObject
{   
    LPWSTR a;    
};
```

I want to print its instance:

```
printf(sampleObject->a);
```

but I got this error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'printf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'LPWSTR' to 'const char *'

How can I convert from `LPWSTR to char*`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just do: `printf((const char*)sampleObject->a);`

Comment: @KristerAndersson super! why dont you answer instead, then I will mark it as an answer! :D

Comment: It's not likely to work... This won't convert the data, it will just tell the compiler not to worry about the fact it's the wrong data type.

Comment: @JohnB you are right. it wont work. I got an exception for that conversion. any idea?

Comment: In C++/CLI, you can just use `marshal_as` to convert directly from `System::String^` to `char*`, no need to go through LPWSTR along the way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't convert.

Use `wprintf` instead of `printf`:

- [wprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

See [the examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which explains how to use it.

Alternatively, you can use `std::wcout` as:

```
wchar_t *wstr1= L"string";
LPWSTR   wstr2= L"string"; //same as above
std::wcout << wstr1 << L", " << wstr2;
```

Similarly, use functions which are designed for wide-char, and forget the idea of converting `wchar_t` to `char`, as it may loss data.

Have a look at the functions which deal with wide-char here:

- [Unicode in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194799.aspx)

Comment: no, I need to convert it to do other things as well. the reason I am asking there is because I first need to debug to see the passing object from c# to C++ working or not

Comment: do you have a sample how to use it? it is not easy as: wsprintf(string)

Comment: Bad recommendation. There are cases where you DO NEED to convert.

Answer (score 28):

Use the `wcstombs()` function, which is located in `<stdlib.h>`. Here's how to use it:

```c
LPWSTR wideStr = L"Some message";
char buffer[500];

// First arg is the pointer to destination char, second arg is
// the pointer to source wchar_t, last arg is the size of char buffer
wcstombs(buffer, wideStr, 500);

printf("%s", buffer);
```

Hope this helped someone! This function saved me from a lot of frustration.

Comment: thanks, it saved my time to convert the LPWSTR so that it can be display by _cprintf()

Comment: even type LPTSTR can use the same method to store in buffer.

Comment: This does not guarantee encoding in UTF-8. Use `WideCharToMultiByte` instead and explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8. See @79E09796 answer for example.

Comment: @andrewrk Which is a much more complicated function, and there cases if we are sure, that the WSTR contains actually only ascii-7 data.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `printf("%ls", sampleObject->a)`. The use of `l` in `%ls` means that you can pass a `wchar_t[]` such as `L"Wide String"`.

(No, I don't know why the L and w prefixes are mixed all the time)

Answer (score 4):

```
int length = WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, sampleObject->a, -1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
char* output = new char[length];
WideCharToMultiByte(cp, 0, sampleObject->a, -1, output , length, NULL, NULL);
printf(output);
delete[] output;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `WideCharToMultiByte()` method to convert multi-byte character.

**Here is example of converting from LPWSTR to char*
or wide character to character.**

```
/*LPWSTR to char* example.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void LPWSTR_2_CHAR(LPWSTR,LPSTR,size_t);

int main(void)
{   
    wchar_t w_char_str[] = {L"This is wide character string test!"};
    size_t w_len = wcslen(w_char_str);
    char char_str[w_len + 1];
    memset(char_str,'\0',w_len * sizeof(char));
    LPWSTR_2_CHAR(w_char_str,char_str,w_len);

    puts(char_str);
    return 0;
}

void LPWSTR_2_CHAR(LPWSTR in_char,LPSTR out_char,size_t str_len)
{   
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,WC_COMPOSITECHECK,in_char,-1,out_char,str_len,NULL,NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Simple Solution. Check [wsprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
LPWSTR wideStr = "some text";
char* resultStr = new char [wcslen(wideStr) + 1];
wsprintfA ( resultStr, "%S", wideStr);
```

The "%S" will implicitly convert UNICODE to ANSI.

Comment: The wsprintf() docs page now has a note warning against its use