# How to convert LPOLESTR to char* in C++

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

When I was trying to retrieve 'Column name' from my stored procedure by using CDynamicStringAccessor then write into the first line of my csv file, I am up to the point which I have to dealing with the conversion from LPOLESTR into char* OR std::string.

After few research, I finally found the simplest way to do it. I will post the answer shortly, hope this will help people who have the same problems.

Comment: `OLECHAR` is the same as `wchar_t` (unless you're in Windows 95), so you can also refer to any of the answers for converting `LPWSTR` .

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [ATL conversion macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx). These allocate from the stack temporarily:

```
USES_CONVERSION;

std::string my_string = OLE2CA(the_lpolestr);
```

See also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839972/how-to-convert-from-lpwstr-to-const-char) for some alternatives, since `OLECHAR` is `wchar_t` since about 1995.

An important alternative is to actually use the wide string as-is without converting it (converting either loses information, or will produce a UTF-8 string which may or may not be appropriate to what you are going to use it for).

Comment: Yea, that is what i did. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score -2):

```
//.................

    LPOLESTR columname = rs.GetColumnName(i);

    //Convert LPOLESTR into LPCSTR <- Which is the const CHAR*....
    //Below Code Related to the question
    USES_CONVERSION;
    LPCSTR szText = OLE2CA(columname);

    //Below code NOT related to the question
    fwrite(szText,sizeof(char),strlenm(szText),pFile);
//....................
```

Comment: This code dose, man:
USES_CONVERSION;
LPCSTR szText = OLE2CA(columname);